# Hibernate Derby connection issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on Hibernate with Derby. But while I am configuring at home I am getting the error "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"

Below are the details of my configuration

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.tut.hib</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hibernate1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.14.2.0</version>
</dependency> -->

 </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

project structure and hibernate.cfg.xml

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver.class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.driver.url">jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Raja/MyDB;create=true;create=true;</property>
        <property name="connection.ussername">derby</property>
        <property name="connection.password">********</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSixDialect</property>
        <!-- <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property> -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="com.tut.hib.dto.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

java class

```
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Raja");

    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    session.saveOrUpdate(user);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
```

UserDetails.class

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
private int userId;
private String userName;

--- getters and setters --
 }
```

exception log:

```
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
 Sep 10, 2019 1:13:20 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
 INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
 Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
 INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: null at URL: null
 Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
  INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {driver.url=jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Raja/MyDB;create=true;create=true;, password=****, driver.class=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver, ussername=derby}
  Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
  INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
  Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
  WARN: HHH10001006: No JDBC Driver class was specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class
  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
  MLog initialization issue: slf4j found no binding or threatened to use its (dangerously silent) NOPLogger. We consider the slf4j library not found.
 Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog 
 INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry 
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH10001007: JDBC isolation level: <unknown>
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:21 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@5c55b9f5 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@8f4049 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> 1hge162a578z3zv1xnz383|62230c58, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@95afa16e [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge162a578z3zv1xnz383|3098cf3b, jdbcUrl -> null, properties -> {driver.url=jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Raja/MyDB;create=true;create=true;, password=******, driver.class=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver, ussername=derby} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge162a578z3zv1xnz383|44821a96, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:51 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3b2bcb9e -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Sep 10, 2019 1:13:51 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@156b88f5 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:52 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSixDialect
Sep 10, 2019 1:13:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Hibernate: drop table UserDetails
Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7ea45ec0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@156b88f5 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1c354f62 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@156b88f5 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1701b716 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Sep 10, 2019 1:14:22 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@156b88f5 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.tut.hib.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

I tried with all type of drivers available in derby.
I tried all the dialects available in Hibernate for derby.
I started derby network server from background also.
I configured the database in data source explorer there I am able to connect to Derby
I set DERBY_HOME, path, lib of Derby.

I tried with both create and create-drop options in hbm2ddl.auto tag.

Still not able to succeed in getting connection.

Any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out the
`<property name="connection.driver.class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>` property. In recent JARs, there is no such driver. Hibernate should infer the driver from the URL.

It has worked for me for an example with a networked Derby database.
http://zetcode.com/hibernate/derby/

Answer (score 0):

it,s connection.url.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ap</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect"<org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="com/zetcode/hibernate/Car.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

'